# Checkboxes in DataTables need to capture all checked values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having 100s of items in my datatable, displayed using 'forEach' in script as below

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="table1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Customer</th>
              
              <th scope="col">CheckBoxes</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${list}" varStatus="status" var="name">
                <tr>      
                    <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
                    <td>${name.getName()}</td>
                    <td>${name.getCustomer()}</td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkRule" value="${rule.getName()}">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

What I am trying is, upon checking respective checkboxes, I need those value to be fetched and sent in AJAX (POST).

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
        
        const myArray = [];
        
        $('#checkRule').click(function(){
            console.log('checked');
            
            if( $('#checkRule').is(':checked') ) {
                myArray.push( $('#checkRule').val() );
                console.log(myArray);
            }else{
                const index = myArray.indexOf( $('#checkRule').val() );
                if (index > -1) {
                  myArray.splice(index, 1);
                }
                console.log(myArray);
            }
            
        });
        
        $('#correlation_table').DataTable();
        
        $('#send').click(function(){
            
            var result = myArray;
            console.dir('Import result >>>>> ',result);
            $.ajax({
                   url: "sendAll",
                   headers: {
                       'Accept': 'text/plain',
                       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                   },
                   type: "POST",
                   dataType: "html",
                   data: JSON.stringify(result),
                   success :function(data) {
                       console.log(data);
                   },
                   error :function(err){
                       console.log(err);
                   }
            });
        });
        
    });
```

Upon using this above code, I am reaching nowhere.
Console output for "console.log('Import result >>>>> ',result);" is

```
Import result >>>>> Array []
```

How can I get all 'Name' upon checking multiple checkboxes in table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  have given  `same ids` to all your checkboxes so only first checkboxes value you will be getting in your array instead use `class` selector instead of `id` and then simply use `$(this)` to get the reference of checkbox change and add those values in your array using `.val()`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  const myArray = [];
  //use class here
  $('.checkRule').change(function() {
    //use `this` to get refernce of current checkbox change
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      myArray.push($(this).val()); //put that value
    } else {
      const index = myArray.indexOf($(this).val());
      if (index > -1) {
        myArray.splice(index, 1);
      }

    }

  });

  $('#correlation_table').DataTable();

  $('#send').click(function() {

    var result = myArray;
    console.log('Import result >>>>> ', result);
    //your ajax call..

  });
});
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


  <table class="table table-striped" id="correlation_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Customer</th>

        <th scope="col">CheckBoxes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>sss</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>
          <!-- use class instead of id-->
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input checkRule" value="ss">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>ses</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input checkRule" value="ses">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>sswi</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input checkRule" value="sswi">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>ssww</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input checkRule" value="ssww">
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="send">SEnd</button>
```

Comment: Hi @Swati
Thank for help, it worked just perfectly as I wanted.